# MySQL 5.7 | GROUP BY | Non Aggregated Column Error

Tags: mysql, sql

I upgraded our mysql db from 5.6 to 5.7 and am in the process of fixing some queries which are throwing some errors. One of the queries I am working involves a GROUP BY with a COALESCE.

Here is the query (abstracted) that works:

```
SELECT 
    MAX(a.id),
    a.entered,
    count(*) AS teh_count
FROM
    a
INNER JOIN
    b ON b.id = a.link_to_b_id
INNER JOIN
    c ON c.link_to_b_id = b.id
WHERE
    b.revision_id > 0
AND
    c.terminated_at = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
AND
    a.created_at > date_sub(NOW(), INTERVAL 8 HOUR)
GROUP BY
    a.entered
ORDER BY
    teh_count DESC
LIMIT
    6;
```

But I need to COALESCE a.entered with c.override, so I tried the following:

```
SELECT 
    MAX(a.id),
    a.entered,
    COALESCE(c.override, a.entered) AS appearance,
    count(*) AS teh_count
FROM
    a
INNER JOIN
    b ON b.id = a.link_to_b_id
INNER JOIN
    c ON c.link_link_to_b_id = b.id
WHERE
    b.revision_id > 0
AND
    c.terminated_at = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
AND
    a.created_at > date_sub(NOW(), INTERVAL 8 HOUR)
GROUP BY
    a.entered
ORDER BY
    teh_count DESC
LIMIT
    6;
```

But MySQL 5.7 now throws the following error: `Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'st_core.tuc.code_appearance_override' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

I assume I can can change the sql_mode, but I'd prefer not too. What the error is telling me makes sense, in that the COALESCE column is not aggregated, so as a test I wrapped it with `MAX` and it works, however it seems kind of hacky to me.

Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: This [in the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html) might be worth more than a cursory glance

Comment: The fields that appear in the `GROUP BY` clause determine how records are grouped together. In your case records are grouped by `entered` field. Hence, all records that belong to the same group share a common `entered` value. Now, these records may have *different* `override` values.

Comment: ... but you get *just one* record returned for each group of `entered` value. If you also want non aggregated field `override` to be returned you have to somehow pick one of the values the field has within each group. `MAX` is one way of doing so.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos: Logically that makes sense, thanks. Practically applied the only difference in our situation between entered and override is custom cAsiNg. But I get what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should also include `a.entered` in your `group by` clause and that's what the error saying. Though not sure why you are grouping by an different column `a.code_entered`?

Your query should look like

```
SELECT 
    MAX(a.id),
    a.entered,
    COALESCE(c.override, a.entered) AS appearance,
    count(*) AS teh_count
FROM
    a
INNER JOIN
    b ON b.id = a.link_to_b_id
INNER JOIN
    c ON c.link_link_to_b_id = b.id
WHERE
    b.revision_id > 0
AND
    c.terminated_at = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
AND
    a.created_at > date_sub(NOW(), INTERVAL 8 HOUR)
GROUP BY
    a.entered,
    COALESCE(c.override, a.entered)
ORDER BY
    teh_count DESC
LIMIT
    6;
```

Comment: My apologies, `code_entered` was supposed to be `entered`, I forgot to correct as part of the abstraction for posting to SO process.

Comment: Ahhh ok so I have to duplicate the COALESCE in the group by clause?

Comment: @MikePurcell, yes .. absolutely. You can as well use the alias name but I prefer using the entire expression

Comment: Thx for the post, I opted to go with @GordonLiff answer as I will stab myself in the eyes with a spork before duplicating code.

Comment: @MikePurcell, that's alright but the answer I provided is ANSI compliant since using alias in `group by` will not work in SQLServer or Oracle .. FYI

Comment: As much as I hate duplicating code, I always try to stick to predetermined standards. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

I think you intend something like this:

```
SELECT MAX(a.id),
       COALESCE(c.override, a.entered) AS appearance,
       count(*) AS the_count
FROM a INNER JOIN
     b
     ON b.id = a.link_to_b_id INNER JOIN
     c
     ON c.link_link_to_b_id = b.id
WHERE b.revision_id > 0 AND
      c.terminated_at = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND
      a.created_at > date_sub(NOW(), INTERVAL 8 HOUR)
GROUP BY appearance
ORDER BY the_count DESC
LIMIT 6;
```

This removes `a.entered` from the `SELECT` list so there is only one column for grouping.  That column can be referenced by table alias in the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: This worked, which surprised me. For some reason I thought I couldn't use a derived value in the group by clause. Thanks.

Comment: @MikePurcell . . . In some databases you can (MySQL and Postgres).  Most others you cannot.

Comment: Actually went with @Rahul answer, even though we won't be switching to oracle anytime soon, I always try to stick to predetermined standards when possible. +1 for the response as it did work. Thanks.